# What's the expression for the type of strike where employees work by applying all regulations to the letter to slow down their execution?

Tags: phrase-request

I read on [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gr%C3%A8ve_perl%C3%A9e&oldid=181638591), [translated with Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=en&text=La%20gr%C3%A8ve%20perl%C3%A9e%20se%20distingue%20de%20la%20gr%C3%A8ve%20du%20z%C3%A8le%2C%20o%C3%B9%20les%20salari%C3%A9s%20s%27en%20tiennent%20%C3%A0%20ex%C3%A9cuter%20leurs%20t%C3%A2ches%20en%20appliquant%20%C3%A0%20la%20lettre%20leur%20description%20et%20tous%20les%20r%C3%A8glements%2C%20afin%20d%27en%20ralentir%20le%20plus%20possible%20l%E2%80%99ex%C3%A9cution%20et%20elle%20se%20distingue%20encore%20de%20bien%20d%27autres%20formes%20de%20gr%C3%A8ves%20%3A%20g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rale%2C%20surprise%2C%20tournante%2C%20sauvage%2C%20sur%20le%20tas%2C%20solidaire%2C%20politique%2C%20de%20la%20faim%20et%20se%20diff%C3%A9rencie%20aussi%20du%20piquet%20de%20gr%C3%A8ve3.%0A%0A&op=translate):

> [During a "[grève du zèle](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%A8ve_du_z%C3%A8le)"], employees stick to performing their duties by applying their description and all regulations to the letter, in order to slow down their execution as much as possible.

"Grève du zèle" is the expression used in French for this type of strike.

What's the proper expression in English to designate this type of strike where employees stick to performing their duties by applying their description and all regulations to the letter, in order to slow down their execution as much as possible?

(NB: from the same Wikipedia page, the term *slowdown* designates a different type of strike)

Comment: Related, but probably not a duplicate: [Term used to describe someone who explicitly follows directions when they know that doing so will result in a negative effect](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/48059/9161)

Comment: I don't think English distinguishes between a "grève du zèle" and a "Grève perlée" In both cases workers disrupt the workplace, while not breaking their contracts.

Answer (score 5):

Wordreference.com offers

(UK) **[work-to-rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work-to-rule)**
and
(US) [slowdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowdown)

As a US resident, I am familiar with *slowdown*.

I think *work-to-rule* means insisting on strict adherence to any available regulation or rule that would allow delaying matters.

[wordreference.com *grève du zèle*](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/gr%C3%A8ve%20du%20z%C3%A8le)

Comment: I have heard "work-to-rule" in the US, as well as "slowdown." They are not the same thing, at least not literally; they may be synonymous or close to it in common speech. "*Grève du zèle*" translates as "zealous strike," I imagine relating to the fervor with which workers apply the strict letter of the rules.

Answer (score 4):

This is not specific to strikes, but we do have the term *malicious compliance*, which Wikipedia defines as “ the behaviour of intentionally inflicting harm by strictly following the orders of a superior while knowing or intending that compliance with the orders will have an unintended or negative result.”

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malicious_compliance